# Regex: check for variations of number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to learn Regex but this is quite a complex question for me to understand: how do you check if one number's characters matches another number's characters? I feel examples will explain this better:

If the number is 12:

- 12 and 21 are true
- 11 and 22 are false

If the number is 323:

- 332, 233 are true
- 222, 223, 232, 233, 322, 333 are false

Here is a sample code to test with (the best Regex I can come up with):

```js
//Testing 12

for (i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
  if (i.toString().match(/[12][12]/)) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}

console.log('#####')

//Testing 332

for (i = 1; i < 999; i++) {
  if (i.toString().match(/[32][32][32]/)) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the digits in your number, sort the digits of your input - and compare the sorted lists.
If the input is a permutation of the original number, the sorted digits arrays should be identical.

This example prints only the permutations of its first argument:

```js
let compareFunc = (initial, arrayToCheck) => {
  let initial_digits = initial.toString().split('');
  initial_digits.sort();
  
  arrayToCheck.forEach(function(item) {
    let item_digits = item.toString().split('');
    item_digits.sort();
    
    if(item_digits.toString() === initial_digits.toString()) {
      console.log(item + ' is a permutation of ' + initial);
    }
  })
}

compareFunc(321, [1,2,123,213]);
```

The use of regular expressions here is very inefficient, as you'll need to start by calculating all the permutations of your number. You usually don't want to go there, as permutations calculation has time complexity of *O(n!)*.

Comment: This is quite an insane amount easier that my approach haha. Thank you for this! :) ... one question though, why do you do the (''+initial) instead of doing initial.toString()?

Comment: @Frank Glad I could help! `''+initial` was just a matter of style. However, I'll edit it just so it'll be consistent with the `.toString()` I used on the arrays :)

Comment: All good, I learnt something new to it wasn't a problem haha :)